# RoR Routes problems . Cities in the start of urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have many links like these:
/articles/...
/albums/...
/photos/...
etc.

I need to use the name of the city in the beginning of urls if the user has choosed it:
/city_name/articles/...
/city_name/albums/...
/city_name/photos/...

But previous links shoul work too (/articles/..., /albums/...)

I tried this:

```
map.articles '/articles/', :controller => "zags", :action => "cities", :using_city => 1
map.articles '/:city_url/articles/', :controller => "zags", :action => "cities", :using_city => 1

<%= link_to "London articles", articles_path, { :city_url => "london", :using_city => 1 } %>
```

But it does not work.
What should I change?
I know, that I can change one of map names "map.articles", but I want to use the same route names in my View code.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just creating your url wrong. It should be like:

```
<%= link_to "London articles", articles_path(:city_url => "london", :using_city => 1) %>
```

You may have conflicts with your articles path as well, because you are using `map.articles` twice. Maybe the second could be `map.articles_by_city ...` to have proper naming. And in this case your link changes like:

```
<%= link_to "London articles", articles_by_city_path(:city_url => "london", :using_city => 1) %>
```

Btw if you are using rails 3 I suggest the following route definition.

```
match "(:city_url/)articles/", :controller => "zags", :action => "cities", :using_city => 1, :as => "articles"
```

This sets up for you both cases, so the `:city_url` became an optional parameter. In this case your path will be just `articles_path` and the url will look like `/articles/`.

If you pass `articles_path("london")` your url will look like `/london/articles/`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a single route:

```
map.articles '(/:city)/articles', :controller => 'zags', :action => 'cities'

<%= link_to "Articles", articles_path %>
<%= link_to "London Articles", articles_path(:city => "london") %>
```